# Unable to use SecretKey in Databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, secret-key, apache-commons-dbutils

I am trying to use the created secret key on databricks using `dbutils.secrets.get(scope="jdbc", key="username")` command; but I get an error saying 'Secret does not exist with scope: jdbc and key: username'.

I am creating the secret key using CLI -

```
databricks secrets put --scope jdbc --key username
```

I can even see the created keys on CLI using the command

```
databricks secrets list --scope jdbc
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thank you!!

Comment: Can you check the bearer token you are using for the CLI is for the same workspace that you are running dbutils in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** You will receive this error message because "**Once you have created a Databricks-backed scope, you can secrets**".

**Steps to create a Databricks-backed secret scope:**

Create a scope using databricks cli:

Cmdlet to create a scope  `databricks secrets create-scope --scope <scope-name>`

Once you have created a Databricks-backed secret scope, you can add secrets.

Cmdlet to create a secret key: `databricks secrets put --scope <scope-name> --key <keyname>`

You can check-out the complete steps to create a Databricks-backed secret scope creation.

[image]

Hope this helps.

---

If this answers your query, do click “Mark as Answer” and "Up-Vote" for the same. And, if you have any further query do let us know.

Comment: The OP already stated that the scope and the secret were successfully created.